# Java 8: Is there a batter way to filter JSONArray?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I came up with this code to filter all the true objects, but can I have it even neater? The intstream and boolean casting are itching me...

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(false);
arr.put(true);
arr.put(false);

//JSONArray is a list of objects
boolean b = IntStream.range(0, arr.length())
        .filter(index -> ((boolean) arr.get(index)) == true)
        .findAny()
        .isPresent();
```

I use

```
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20180813</version>
```

dependency. Is it the best selection?

Comment: Please provide information on where you are getting JSONArray. Is this a library?

Comment: @DaveG updated the code with imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) with [getBoolean](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#getBoolean-int-):

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(false);
arr.put(true);
arr.put(false);

//JSONArray is a list of objects
boolean b = IntStream.range(0, arr.length())
        .anyMatch(arr::getBoolean);

System.out.println(b);
```

**Output**

```
true
```

As an alternative you could use the following:

```
boolean b = StreamSupport.stream(arr.spliterator(), false)
                .anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals);
```

The above solution does handle the JSONException problem, for instance it returns `true` for the following input:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        arr.put(false);
        arr.put(1);
        arr.put(true);
```

Comment: It needs to handle JSONException.

Comment: @DanielMesejo IntStream.range(0, arr.length())
        .anyMatch(arr::getBoolean); definitely do the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
boolean b = arr.toList().stream().anyMatch(x -> (Boolean) x);
```